# How to remove a package from pnpm store, or force re-download it?

Tags: pnpm

I use pnpm to manage npm project, and I modified the content of an installed package by accident, say, I cleared the content of `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js`.

The problem is no matter how i reinstall jquery(`pnpm install jquery`), the content of this file is always empty. I even tried to delete `jquery` from pnpm store `~/.pnpm-store/`, but that doesn't work(maybe I deleted wrong package)

Finally, I have to delete all the files in `~/.pnpm-store`, to download everything, it fixes my problem, but I want to know if there is any easier way to do it.

Answer (score 22):

{ My answer will cover pnpm `v2.16.2` }

Short answer: run `pnpm install --force`. (`pnpm update` might work as well)

Long answer. When you just run `pnpm install`, pnpm compares the wanted shrinkwrap file (`project/shrinkwrap.yaml`) to the current one (`project/node_modules/.shrinkwrap.yaml`). They equal in your case, so `node_modules` is not touched.

When `--force` is used, packages are reverified and relinked from the store. Reverification means that its integrity is checked. You removed a file from `jquery`, so verification will fail and the package will be reunpacked to the store and relinked to `node_modules`.

Alternatively, you could remove your project's `node_modules` and run `pnpm install`. That would also check the integrity of `jquery` before linking it to the store.

---

That being said, I think `pnpm install jquery` should also probably verify the integrity of jquery. We'll create an issue for this in the pnpm repo.

And maybe we can add some additional commands for reverifying every package in `node_modules` and re-unpacking all modified dependencies.

A related command currently available is [pnpm store status](https://pnpm.js.org/docs/en/pnpm-store.html#pnpm-store-status) which prints a list of mutated packages

Comment: does reverification will also reinstall if needed? meaning, delete the faulty files from store, downloading them again, etc

Comment: Yes, it will remove broken file from the store and redownload them from the registry.